# Exposing Swagger-UI documentation through Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-ui, gcloud, openapi

I am trying to publish my API docs in the same Nodejs application as my API, using Google Cloud Endpoints.

It looks easy following this guide:
[Adding Swagger UI](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/adding-swagger)

The tricky part is exposing the `/docs` path via Google Cloud Endpoints (it also uses the same `openapi.yaml`).

I have tried defining the `/docs` path in my `openapi.yaml` like this:

```
"/docs":
    get:
      description: "Swagger UI API documentation"
      operationId: "docs"
      produces:
        - "text/html"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Swagger UI"
```

The HTML page itself gets served but any assets like `swagger-ui.css` are not found.

It looks to me I am doing this wrong, as documentation is not an API endpoint. However I haven't been able to find a nice solution. Is there a way to proxy all traffic for `/docs` path?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to find that there is no nice way of doing this. Your best bet is going to be to break off documentation publishing as a separate step in your deployment pipeline. That, or wait 6 months. Google Cloud is evolving rapidly and they've probably got this on their roadmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating the Swagger UI dist in one file (index.html)

**or** you can add

> x-google-allow: all

in your openapi.yaml file to to expose all paths that don't have any form of authentication already set. Please note that this will allow all paths that follow the basepath of the .yaml file to be exposed in your Endpoints. (So for instance, if your basepath is `/api` then `x-google-allow: all` will only apply to paths following this (i.e. `/api/users`)

Also, please see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/2h-2fotar9k

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this path *(you can add this below the existing one, but do not replace)* to handle CSS/JS files.

```
"/docs/*":
    get:
      description: "Swagger UI API documentation"
      operationId: "docs-dependencies"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Swagger UI"
```

Previously, on logs, it returns 404 for the CSS/JS Files.

[image]

Adding that path fixed my blank SwaggerUI.

Somehow, **x-google-allow: all** did not work on my end.

Hope this helps!